# ffmpeg set duration when converting

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm converting video with ffmpeg and after conversation duration is shown as 00:00:00.00.
here is my passing arguments

```
"-i " + FileName + " -ar 22050 -b 500k -f flv -t " + Duration + " " + outputfile
```

Which is rendered by my code to

```
-i 1.mov -ar 22050 -b 500k -f flv -t 00:03:34.99 1.flv
```

what am I missing?

---

```
filargs = "flvtool2 -UP " + outputfile;
            proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = spath + "flvtool2.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = filargs;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;

            proc.Start();

            proc.WaitForExit();
            proc.Close();
```

I've tried this, no effect, duration is still 0. where "outputfile" is my converted file who has no duration

Comment: have you checked that the duration you are passing it is correct (in seconds or hh:mm:ss[.xxx])?  Does the output file play correctly and just report an incorrect duration, or does it not play at all?  Can you try the same command from the command line and paste the output from ffmpeg here.

Comment: Here is my exact command. 
-i 1.mov -ar 22050 -b 500k -f flv -t 00:03:34.99 1.flv

conversation proceeds successfully, but some players can't see duration an seek line is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I see the same problem in a test I just ran.  This appears to be a known issue in ffmpeg.  For flv, it does not properly write all of the metadata, including the duration.  You can use [flvtool2](http://www.inlet-media.de/flvtool2/) to fix the metadata for you.  Just run:

```
flvtool2 -UP file.flv
```

and it will automatically find the duration based on the timestamps and write the metadata to the file.  I just tried it and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem

```
static void Fix(string Path)
        {
            string spath;
            spath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            string filargs = "-U " + Path;
            Process proc1 = new Process();
            proc1.StartInfo.FileName = spath + "flvtool2.exe";
            proc1.StartInfo.Arguments = filargs;
            proc1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            proc1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput
= false;
            proc1.Start();
            proc1.WaitForExit();
            proc1.Close();
        }
```

it does the perfect job